# Calling validation methods from textbox mouse leave Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to call a validation function which is located in a controller from a view elements like "input box". e.g : gmail signup page username field validate when mouse leave...

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use ajax to do this.

documentation for `$.ajax();` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url/to/controller/validationaction",
  success: function(data){
    //do something since validation
    //passed.
  },
  error: function(d,r,x){
    //do something since validation
    //failed.
  }
});
```

is a very very remedial example.

Your controller would return an http failure status code using

```
$this->output->set_status_header(code, 'text');
```

[Link to CI's Output Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html)

[list of http status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

if the validation failed, otherwise `return TRUE;` or echo a json_encoded array of a message..

```
$message = array(
  'message' => 'Success!',
  'type' => 'succes',
);
echo json_encode($message);
```

### Using jQuery Validation

You could also rely on jquery/javascript to handle your validation client side, this would prevent you from having to make an http request just to validate the user's input.

One popular plugin for this is: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It should go noted that, if the user disables jquery/javascript you need to have a failsafe method in place that will validate via codeigniters form validation helper still.